# What modules does mod_rewrite depend on?

Tags: apache, apache2

proxy? proxy_http? what else?

When I include all of the available modules, rewrite works, but I'm having a hard time figuring out which ones are actually making the difference.

ANSWER: `vhost_alias` was one. seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite in itself does not have any direct dependencies. There are a few directives that  can delegate work to other modules (like RewriteRule .... [P], which uses mod_proxy to execute the request) thus requiring additional modules.

Answer (score 1):

To have mod_rewrite working,
first, you have to turn it on. 
in httpd.conf
uncomment this: LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/mod_rewrite.so
and restart Apache.

If you use .htaccess to manage the mod_rewrite, then you need to activate that as well.
and set AllowOverride.

reference: http://www.usenet-forums.com/apache-web-server/10742-activate-mod_rewrite.html

and http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=33314
and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride